# MBA dissertation without any mathematical equations in it?

Tags: masters

I do not understand maths.Total ignoramus ...Is it possible to do a MBA dissertation without once referring to any equations ? eg: a-b=???

Comment: I'm not in this field, but a certain formalism always helps to point out things precisely.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. It certainly makes STEM people feel dislike it, but it is still a good question.

Comment: @scaaahu It might be a fine question, but it is formulated in an utterly terrible way, with the barest minimum of effort put into even making it comprehensible.

Answer (score 2):

I teach statistics to social science students, so I see this fear of math a lot. I have taught now in the 1000s of students, and have come across only one case where there was a true inability to do math. All the other cases it was just fear blocking their ability to do math, and you can overcome fear. So rather than avoid the problem, a more productive way forward would be to face your problem and solve it.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.I do appreciate your valuable time.My apologies for the way I placed this question.I am new to the forum and at the moment my burning question(I spend hours reading other dissertations), is how I can avoid having equations explaining my view point.If I do interviews I have to process and explain in a numerical equation so that it has a meaning.I battle with this and will keep searching for a way to overcome it without making my dissertation look like a high school essay.I do appreciate the comments.Negative or positive, I learn from each one.

Comment: Your key problem seems to be "If I do interviews I have to process and explain in a numerical equation so that it has a meaning". Can you say more about that? Why do you think that statement is true, and if so, why do you think that that is a problem?

Comment: Maarten Buis, thank you for helping me .Really apprecaite it.In all the dissertation's that I read, part of the methodology seem to involve reducing your research to a mathematical problem.I read statements that conclude :I have sent out a 100 interviews and received back 75. The probability of my answer is based on I < 100 but > 75! This is really confusing to me.I am bad at explaining this problem.I It is embaresing,I have been researching for years, but still, not able to overcome this hurdle.

Comment: This is what methodology courses are for. Some people can get this via self study, but most need a course to structure the information for them. Your MBA program may offer such courses, but you may need a more basic (undergraduate) to get the basics.

Comment: Think of it this way: in your later career you will be required to (pretend you) understand such statements, so learning what they mean now is right.

Comment: Thank you Martin.I eventually got that answer from uni.You reach the same conclusion with the sparse info I was able to supply.Thank you again.